# How to get the name of INBOUND ENDPOINT in ESB WSO2

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I need to get the name of the inbound endpoint in my sequence, I know I can get the name of proxy or api as follow:

`expression="$ctx:proxy.name"  expression="$ctx:SYNAPSE_REST_API"`

how do i do it for IEP ?

Comment: Why you need to get the name of the inbound?

Comment: for logging purposes, they need to send this info to our kibana server.

Comment: inbound endpoint names are predefined. Then why you need to get through expression? 
https://github.com/wso2/carbon-mediation/blob/master/components/mediation-ui/org.wso2.carbon.inbound.ui/src/main/java/org/wso2/carbon/inbound/ui/internal/InboundClientConstants.java

Comment: <inboundEndpoint xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse"
                 name="GetAllFiles.iep"
                 sequence="SomeSequence.seq"
                 onError="FaultHandlerSequence.seq"
                 protocol="file"
                 suspend="true">   i need to get that name attribute and pass it through.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get it with: $ctx:inbound.endpoint.name